# Problem comparing two arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have a loop in Objective C and i compare two index of the same array but the comparison doesnt work ,there is no compile error. Variable iMinor is always zero and arrayDistancias is not empty:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayDistancias = [NSMutableArray array];


NSNumber *lat1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:39.0025];
NSNumber *lat2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:40.2710];
NSNumber *lat3 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:38.5316];
NSNumber *lat4 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:27.4529];
NSNumber *lng1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1.5139];
NSNumber *lng2 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-3.4327];
NSNumber *lng3 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-7.0029];
NSNumber *lng4 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-15.3432];


//for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 40; i++)
[arrayDistancias addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self calcularDistancia:latitudaqui :lat1 :longitudaqui :lng1]]];
[arrayDistancias addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self calcularDistancia:latitudaqui :lat2 :longitudaqui :lng2]]];
[arrayDistancias addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self calcularDistancia:latitudaqui :lat3 :longitudaqui :lng3]]];
[arrayDistancias addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self calcularDistancia:latitudaqui :lat4 :longitudaqui :lng4]]];


int iMinor = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [arrayDistancias count]; i++) {

        if([arrayDistancias objectAtIndex: i] < [arrayDistancias objectAtIndex: iMinor]){
            iMinor = i;
          }              


     }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`[arrayDistances objectAtIndex: i]` retuns the `NSNumber` object, not the integer value. In order to get the integer value use `intValue` method on the returned object. So, you should compare it like this.

```
if ([[arrayDistances objectAtIndex: i] intValue] < 
   [[arrayDistances objectAtIndex: iMinor] intValue]) {
```

Comment: Just a note in the example float are used, so you could use `floatValue` to get the float value. Or just use `compare` method of `NSNumber`. `if ([[arrayDistances objectAtIndex: i] compare:[arrayDistances objectAtIndex: iMinor]] == NSOrderedAscending)`